# Javamail /hMailServer 550 Delivery is not allowed to this address

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to `send emails with javamail and a local smtp serveur (hMailServer)`.
Could you tell me if javmail is the best way to send email with java?

Then i have an error that tells me =>  **550 Delivery is not allowed to this address**
I dont understand if it is the format of it or it is the adress it self:

STACKTRACE:

```
SEVERE: Erreur dans le message
SEVERE: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;<br>
```

`nested exception is:`

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 Delivery is not allowed to this address.
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1835)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1098)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at dao.SendEmail.sendEmail(SendEmail.java:51)
at beans.ActionBean.ajouter(ActionBean.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 Delivery is not allowed to this address.
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1686)
    ... 45 more

```
public void sendEmail(Action action) {
    if (action.getCopieAction() != null) {
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            String host = "localhost";
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.setProperty("mail.from", "sakina@transat.fr");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            UtilisateurDao user = new UtilisateurDao();
            // récupération du code user de l'utilisateur

            Integer codeUserEnCopie = action.getCopieAction();
            System.out.println(codeUserEnCopie);
            Utilisateur util = user.findUserByCode(91);
            String mailUserCopie = util.getEmail();
            System.out.println(mailUserCopie);
            InternetAddress recipient = new InternetAddress(mailUserCopie);
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipient);
            message.setSubject("Vous êtes en copie d'une action");

            message.setText("Bonjour, l'utilisateur "
                    + action.getUtilCreation()
                    + " vous à mis en copie d'une action:"
                    + "Nom de l'action : " + action.getObjetAction()
                    + "Détails de l'action : " + action.getTexteAction()
                    + "Date de l'action : " + action.getDateAction());

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Pas de transport disponible pour ce protocole");
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            System.err.println("Adresse invalide");
            System.err.println(e);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.err.println("Erreur dans le message");
            System.err.println(e);

        }

    }

}
```

Delivry and sender adress are the same, i have tried with other adresses like gmail or hotmail it is still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail is the best way to send email using Java.

The error comes from your mail server.  It's complaining about a particular recipient address.  You'll need to check your mail server configuration to understand why it doesn't want to allow you to send to that address.  It might be as simple as [you've failed to login to your mail server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth), so it doesn't know who you are, and thus won't let you send to that address.  The [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) would provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you use javamail the adress you put in the FROM field must be an existing account in your hmailServer, even if the server is phisically the same, if the FROM field is not created in hMailServer you get this error.

```
// The following account must be created in a hMailServer domain called qqq.com 
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxx@qqq.com"));
```